# Redux Form Validation error while using field names like user.name

Tags: reactjs, validation, redux, redux-form

I have a react component with a redux form as below

```
<div className="col-sm-12">
 <div className="form-group row">
  <div className="col-sm-4">
   <label>A. Name</label>
  </div>
  <div className="col-sm-8">
  <ul className="sub-qn-ans-list d-flex list-unstyled">
    <li>
      <Field
      name="first_name"
      component={renderField}
      type="text"
      placeholder="First name"
      className="form-control" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <Field
      name="last_name"
      component={renderField}
      placeholder="Last name"
      type="text"
      className="form-control" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div className="form-group row">
<div className="col-sm-4">
  <label>B. Residential Address</label>
</div>
<div className="col-sm-8">
  <ul className="sub-qn-ans-list d-flex list-unstyled">
    <li>
      <Field
        name="residential.street"
        component={renderField}
        placeholder="Street"
        type="text"
        className="form-control" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <Field
        name="residential.area"
        component={renderField}
        placeholder="Area"
        type="text"
        className="form-control" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <Field
        name="residential.city"
        component={renderField}
        placeholder="City"
        type="text"
        className="form-control" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <Field
        name="residential.district"
        component={renderField}
        placeholder="District"
        type="text"
        className="form-control" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <Field
        name="residential.landline"
        component={renderField}
        placeholder="Landline"
        type="text"
        className="form-control" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <Field
        name="residential.mobile"
        component={renderField}
        placeholder="Mobile"
        type="text"
        className="form-control" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to apply validations for the input fields. The validation for the fields `first_name` and `last_name` works fine. But I get an error when I'm trying to apply validation for `residential.street`.

Below is my code for the validation.

```
const LocatorValidation = (values, form) => {
const errors = {};
if (!values.first_name) {
  errors.first_name = 'Required';
} else if (!/[A-Za-z.]+/.test(values.first_name)) {
  errors.first_name = 'First name must have only alphabets';
}
if (!values.last_name) {
  errors.last_name = 'Required';
} else if (!/^[A-Za-z.]+$/.test(values.last_name)) {
  errors.last_name = 'First name must have only alphabets';
}
if (!values.residential) {
  errors.residential.street = 'Required';
}
return errors;
}

export default LocatorValidation;
```

Here is the image which shows the error.
[image]

Comment: try to change residential.street to residential_street

Comment: the initial values are coming from an api where the structure of the object has a residential object.

Comment: like this: 

residential
:
{id: 18, locator_id: 3, first_name: null, last_name: null, street: "bnbnb", city: "bmnbnb",…}
area
:
"bnbn"
city
:
"bmnbnb"
contactable_type
:
"residential"
created_at
:
"2018-08-30T06:23:41.563Z"
district
:
"nmnb"
first_name
:
null
id
:
18
landline
:
"bnbnb"
last_name
:
null
locator_id
:
3
mobile
:
"nbnbn"
relationship
:
null
street
:
"bnbnb"
updated_at
:
"2018-08-30T06:23:41.563Z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states in `errors.residential.street` the `residential` property of `errors` is undefined. So you need to set it as empty object first like

```
errors.residential = {}
errors.residential.street = "Required"
```

I would also improve the check

```
!values.residential || !values.residential.street
```